# How to automatically copy all emails sent and recieved to another folder on the server

Tags: email, email-server

I am trying to work out a solution to the following:

a few hundred users use the email system, all of their emails, both sent and received in the future need to be copied to a separate folder for legal reasons.

the users are using round cube and their phones for email.

how can this be done? and do I need anything in particular to achieve this? such as a dedicated server.

Comment: Roundcube is only the web interface for your email. What SMTP server are you using? You can sometimes configure an "archive" address there, to get a BCC: of every message sent through it, inbound and outbound.

Comment: using the default SMTP with our shared host (justhost)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The crude way is to setup your own mailserver and attach and alias to all the emails created to one particular email box ( its similar to a server side BCC ) you would be able to specify for all incoming as well as outgoing. From here all you have to do is administer that particular inbox or it will get VERY MESSY VERY QUICK